# Android studio preview not showing option to change JDK

Tags: android, android-studio

On Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Canary 14, I cannot find the option to change JDK version in preferences. Can anyone help with this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check / change the JDK of Android Studio Arctic Fox here.
File -> Settings -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK
[image]